# Use Substitution or partial integration to solve $\int x\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm struggling with the following homework:

Use Substitution or partial integration to solve

$$\int x\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx$$

Ok, so since we have a multiplication, partial integration seems like the right choice:

$$\int f'(x)g(x)\,dx = f(x)g(x)-\int f(x)g'(x)\,dx$$

$$f'(x) = x, g(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2} \Rightarrow f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2, g'(x) = -\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

So I end up with

$$\frac{1}{2}x^2 \cdot \sqrt{1-x^2} - \int \frac{-x^3}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$$

But this is in no way easier to integrate than the expression I started with. So where am I going wrong?

Comment: Consider using the substitution $u=1-x^2$ in the original integral; it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Try $\sin u=x$ for substitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int\sqrt{1-x^2}\Big( x\,dx \Big)
$$

Writing these huge parentheses around $x\,dx$ should be taken as a hint.  It tells you what substitution to use.  If you don't perceive that as a hint, then you need to work on your understanding of how integration by substitution works.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Start from this: $2x\,dx=d(x^2)$ and note that $d(1-x^2)=-2x\,dx.$